# How to export SVG to PDF without images with relative path, using Inkscape?

Tags: command-line, pdf, inkscape

I'm using Inkscape to create a SVG file and export this file to PDF. Then, I'm using this command:

```
./inkscape --file=my.svg --export-area-drawing --without-gui --export-pdf=my.pdf
```

I'm using command line because I'm making a tool to automate the process (create SVG and export to PDF).

But, my SVG files have images with relative linking, then, I need embedding this images in PDF. I can make this using command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When exporting PDF, inkscape automatically embeds the linked images into the file it exports. So if the command succeeds and contains the linked image, you don't have to worry about the portability of the PDF.

If the exported PDF contains the error message "linked image not found", then inkscape has not found it *at the time the inkscape command was run*. To solve this, you can either provide the linked image in the correct path relative to the current location of SVG file, or provide the absolute path in the `xlink:href` attributes (this can be done by automatic parsing, e.g. with `sed`)